# Maximum call stack size exceeded with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get an error with jQuery and I don't understand why...

My error : Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

My code :

The "getSelected" function return an object and the "editeTextOfSelectedCase" update the "getSelected" object...

```
        var removeCaseToEditableMode = function removeCaseToEditableMode($case){
            getSelectedCase().isEditable = false;
            $case.attr('contenteditable', false);
            $case.attr('id', '');
            editeTextOfSelectedCase($case);
            var $rightCase = getSelectedCase().$rightCase; // error with these two last lines ...
            selectCase($rightCase);
        };
```

Edit #2:

```
        var getSelectedCase = function getSelectedCase(){
            var $selectedCaseFound = false;
            $.each(cases, function(index, value){
                if( value.isSelected ){
                    $selectedCaseFound = value;
                }
            });
            return $selectedCaseFound;
        };

        var editeTextOfSelectedCase = function editeTextOfSelectedCase($case){
            getSelectedCase().preventText = getSelectedCase().newText;
            getSelectedCase().newText = $case.text();
        };

        var selectCase = function selectCase($case){
            unselectCase();
            cases[$case.data('index')].isSelected = true;
            setCssOfCase($case);
        };

        var unselectCase = function unselectCase(){
            if( getSelectedCase() === false )
                return false;
            removeCssOfCase(getSelectedCase().$element);
            removeCaseToEditableMode(getSelectedCase().$element);
            cases[getSelectedCase().$element.data('index')].isSelected = false;
        };

        var setCssOfCase = function setCssOfClickedCase($case){
            $case.addClass('selectedCase');
            $case.addClass(params.class);

            getSelectedCase().$topCase.addClass('pointer');
            getSelectedCase().$rightCase.addClass('pointer');
            getSelectedCase().$bottomCase.addClass('pointer');
            getSelectedCase().$leftCase.addClass('pointer');
        };
```

Edit #3:

```
    var $this = $(this),
        $cases = $this.find('td'),
        cases = [],
        _case = {};

    $cases.each( function(index){
        $this = $(this);

        _case = {
            $element: $this,
            isSelected: false,
            preventText: $this.text(),
            newText: $this.text(),
            caseNumbersInCurrentLine: $this.parent().find('td').length,
            lineNumbersInCurrentCase: $this.parent().parent().find('tr').length,
            index: $this.index(),
            lineIndex: $this.parent().index(),
            topIndexLine: $this.parent().index()-1,
            topIndexCase: $this.index(),
            rightIndexLine: $this.parent().index(),
            rightIndexCase: ( $this.index() - $this.parent().find('td').length ) + 1,
            bottomIndexLine: ( $this.parent().index() - $this.parent().parent().find('tr').length ) + 1,
            bottomIndexCase: $this.index(),
            leftIndexLine: $this.parent().index(),
            leftIndexCase: $this.index()-1,
            isEditable: false
        };

        _case.$topCase = $this.parent().parent().find('tr').eq(_case.topIndexLine).find('td').eq(_case.topIndexCase);
        _case.$rightCase = $this.parent().find('td').eq(_case.rightIndexCase);
        _case.$bottomCase = $this.parent().parent().find('tr').eq(_case.bottomIndexLine).find('td').eq(_case.bottomIndexCase);
        _case.$leftCase = $this.parent().find('td').eq(_case.leftIndexCase);

        cases.push(_case);
        $this.data('index', index);
    });
```

Comment: `var removeCaseToEditableMode = function($case){ ... }`

Comment: Seems like some kind of recursion error. Does `selectCase()` somehow call `getSelectedCase()` or something like that?

Comment: @hsz, having a named anonymous function expression (I know that doesn't make sense) helps with debugging, so that's fine I think.

Comment: can you post the other two functions?

Comment: Edit#2 : Other function...

Comment: Where is `cases` declared? Doesn't `getSelectedCase()` return a boolean, how can you set properties on it? Learn to use variables and call `getSelectedCase()` only once per function!

Comment: Maybe the stack overflow isn't caused by `removeCaseToEditableMode` at all, it just might be called by the flawed function(s). Please get the **call stack** from the exception and post it.

Comment: `getSelectedCase()` return a boolean or an object... See edit#3 for `cases` ...

Comment: In `removeCaseToEditableMode` function when I put `console.log(getSelectedCase())`, `getSelectedCase()` is not empty...